# Variable in JSON API POST Request is not working

Tags: javascript, json, retool

[image: The first image is the transformer I am building in Retool, all this is doing is building my JSON string for the API call]

[image: This image is where I am inputting the value of the JSON string into the API POST call. As you can see, the value of the transformer is the same as what I hardcode]

I am making an API to Carbone (PDF generator site) to generate a PDF based on JSON data that I provide. This is all being done through Retool which uses JavaScript and is an app building application.

I have a JSON string saved as a variable:

```
jsonString = '{
"products": [{"name": "Fred"},
  {"name": "Abby"},
  {"name": "Jason"},
  {"name": "Josh"}]
              }'
```

This is a string variable.

When I hardcode this into the API call data parameter, the PDF returns just fine. However, when I input this variable into the call, the PDF does not generate at all.

Am I missing something? I have already tried deleting the first and last character of the string in case for some reason quotes were being added to the variable but it did not fix anything.

```
{
"products": [{"name": "Fred"},
  {"name": "Abby"},
  {"name": "Jason"},
  {"name": "Josh"}]
              }
```

^ This is the hardcoded value I can enter in the data parameter for the API call and it works.

Comment: Please show hardcoded and not hardcoded version

Comment: I added the hardcoded value to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to JSON.stringify( jsonSting ) before or when loading the call. This is only if your json is returned as an object and not a string.

Carbone requires the data to be passed in as an object or array. The following should fix the issue.

If needing to send in an object and you have a string use JSON.parse( jsonString ) to make string and object before or when loading the call.

Comment: No, I have the semicolon in my code. I just wrote that as an example.

Comment: place a larger scope of the code to get better help.

Comment: Just added pictures at the top of the question to better explain

Comment: I see you doing a console log just before the return of your JSONString. what does that console log give you?
Also is there a reason you are doing all the concats instead of just loading the values?

Comment: The console.log(JSONString) returns: {"products": [{"name": "Jason"},{"name": "Jason "},{"name": "Jason "},{"name": "Josh"}]}

Comment: And I'm doing the concats because the number of values is dynamic so I cannot just load them in. I have to run this transformer so that I can get a fixed-length JSON beforehand.

Comment: copy and paste that return into the call and let me know if it works.

Comment: Yep, it works. Maybe it's an issue with the API

Comment: I suspect that the issue is that you are getting a JSON response and the call needs to be stringified. need to use JSON.stringify() before loading it to the call.

Comment: So in this case you're suggesting to add JSON.stringify(JSONString) in the transformer?

Comment: So you are returning the object from your builder. the response needs to be placed in JSON.stringify(JSONString) before or at the time of loading the call.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: You can do it right on the return.

Comment: Still no dice, I might just wait 24 hours for the Retool support team

Comment: So is your console log returning an object?

Comment: No, it is returning a string

Comment: This should fix it. I noticed that carbone pdf needs the data to be an object or array not a string.

Comment: Thank you so much. I used JSON.parse(JSONString) to do it but you were spot on. If you make a reply saying that I'll mark that as the answer. Seriously thanks that was so frustrating.